# How to change c:forEarch end value dynamically

Tags: jsp, foreach, count, jstl

I have one c:forEach loop in my jsp file where I am using begin and end attribute to restrict loop to some fixed count.

Suppose I have list of banners (say 5) but i want to show only top 3 banners then i can use begin, end like this

`count = 3`

```
<c:forEach items="${banners}" var="banner" varStatus="status" begin="0" end="${count}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${ycommerce:evaluateRestrictions(banner)}">
       <!-- code here -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <c:set var="count" value="${count+1}" />
    </c:otherwise>          
</c:forEach>
```

Here in the above code, if banner 1 having restriction, then I am trying to increment count value plus one (+1) so that `end` will increase to one dynamically.

**But it is not working. Though count is increasing but for loop is not reflecting.**

I tried using scope attribute as well but nothing happened

```
<c:set var="count" value="${count+1}" scope="page" />
```

Please help me to give some solution so that for loop end value change dynamically.

If it is not possible, please suggest me some other alternative.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${count}` is evaluated at the beginning of the loop, so changing the value of `count` during the loop will have no effect.

Also note that, unlike normally for Java, `end` is inclusive, so if you want 3 iterations, use `start="0" end="2"`.

If you want to both filter and limit, then you cannot use `begin`/`end`. Instead, do it yourself in the loop:

```xml
<c:set var="count" value="${0}" />
<c:forEach items="${banners}" var="banner" varStatus="status">
   <c:if test="${count lt 3 and ycommerce:evaluateRestrictions(banner)}">
       <c:set var="count" value="${count+1}" />
       <!-- code here -->
   </c:if>          
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yes i did the same after that, and you also gave the same answer :)